# How to add powershell script to Windows 7 Home Premium startup?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

Win 7 Home Premium doesn't have gpedit.msc as you know so, how to add startup script to Windows?

Start Menu entry doesn't work cause i need to have administrative rights for the script to run

Comment: Why did you use the [diskpart] tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to schedule a logon or startup event using the task scheduler.

Comment: And this will run as admin? i already tried that but unfortunately the script doesn't get the necessary rights

Comment: There's a box that you can check to run the task with the highest privs. Check it.

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: Working flawless